# Javascript anonymous function not updating global variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables, anonymous-function

I've got a $.getJSON call in some code that appear to be not updating a global variable, and I'm at a loss to understand why. The JSON data is being loaded OK, but for some reason the global EventOptions array is not being updated in the for {} loop. The capitalised comments refer to the variable. Any ideas? Thanks

```
function LoadMeasurementTypes() {
    // Clear out EventOptions
    EventOptions = ["..."];
    // Push a couple on to EventOptions - THESE ADD OK
    EventOptions.push("Temperature");
    EventOptions.push("Pulse rate");
    // Call json to get measurementTypes off the table    
    $.getJSON('./get-measurement-types.php', function (measurementTypeData) {
        // Process each json element ([0].BP, [1].ph (Urine) etc.
        for (var i = 0; i < measurementTypeData.length; ++i) {
            // e is a storage variable to contain the current element
            var e = measurementTypeData[i];
            // Add the new measurement type
            alert(e.measure_type); // OK works - we can see the measure_type
            EventOptions.push(e.measure_type); // THESE ARE NOT BEING ADDED 
        }
    } // end anonymous function
    ) // end get json call
    EventOptions.push("Last one"); // THIS ONE IS BEING ADDED
}
```

Comment: is EventOptions declared outside of that function?

Answer (score 2):

Your `EventOptions[]` is not globally visible. My guess would of been that it should still be visible locally to your $.getJSON call; but because it is now scoped to jquery, its clearly obscured (did you `alert(EventOptions);` inside your anon function to test?.

To properly scope, just declare it outside of `LoadMeasureTypes()`.

```
var EventOptions = ["..."];
function LoadMeasureTypes(){...
```

-update

if this does not work - you could always pull the anonymous function outside of the $.getJSON() and assign it a variable name:

```
var retreiveTypes = function(){...};

$.getJSON("..path/php", retreiveTypes);
```

Comment: Thanks, but yes EventOptions was declared globally, and the alert DOES report e.measure_type correctly. Tried the window.EventOptions (thanks pap), but that doesn't work either. Noodling around, it looks as if that damn EventOptions variable in the anonymous function refused to be global!

Comment: I didn't mean to alert(e.measure_type), as you indicate that is working. I meant alter(EventOptions), to determine scope within the anon function. This may also be an issue of browser - I know IE and FF/Chrome deal with scope differently in minor ways ( trace out the "this" keyword in an anonymous function - IE references the window, while ff/chrome ref the function itself. Painful.)

Answer (score 1):

```
window.EventOptions = ["..."]
```

Good 'ol "hack" to put stuff in the global context

Comment: More doodling: no matter what I do I can't get any recognition of global vars in that anonymous function, although the data is definitely updated within the anonymous code block.     Ah well back to the drawing board of redesigning what I'm doing naughty javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer: well kind of. It won't work on iTouch Safari, but is fine on Firefox (Mac). Bosworth I'm figuring it's a browser issue you noted above.
Interestingly, it may be something to do with threads. It appear the out loop runs before the inner anonymous loop has finished (the alerts are not in sequence!). I didn't think javascript used threads this way, but I may be wrong.

I now suspect the whole issue is a timing one - with a new thread as an anonymous function not completing in time.

Thanks guys.

Comment: Browser inconsistency hurts. Bad. Glad you got it sorted.